# Building msg in c++

Tags: ros, c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to construct a message in c++. I am using Ros kinetic, ubuntu 16.04.
I have a message that consists of a list of the Point message from geometry_msgs. The message looks as follows:

```
geometry_msgs/Point[] points
```

I use this message to transport a list of xy coordinates. The next node uses these coordinates to filter a distance from a pointcloud msg. The part were it goes wrong is when I try to construct the message that the second node publishes. This has to be a list, similair to the one that is sent from the first node. However, this should consist of xyz coordinates. The code I am using (if more is desired I'll add it):

```
void pixelTo3DPoint(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pCloud, coord_proces::xyz xy_coord)
{
    // get width and height of 2D point cloud data
    int width = pCloud.width;
    int height = pCloud.height;
    int step;
    int n = 0;
    float min_x = 0;
    float min_y = 0;
    float min_z = 0;

    int list_size = xy_coord.points.size();

    float z_List[list_size];
    float y_List[list_size];
    float x_List[list_size];     

    coord_proces::xyz obj_coords;
    geometry_msgs::Point pt;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++)
    { 
        const int u = static_cast<int>(xy_coord.points[i].x);
        const int v = static_cast<int>(xy_coord.points[i].y);

        // Convert from u (column / width), v (row/height) to position in array
        // where X,Y,Z data starts
        int arrayPosition = v*pCloud.row_step + u*pCloud.point_step;

        // compute position in array where x,y,z data start      
        int arrayPosX = arrayPosition + pCloud.fields[0].offset; // X has an offset of 0
        int arrayPosY = arrayPosition + pCloud.fields[1].offset; // Y has an offset of 4
        int arrayPosZ = arrayPosition + pCloud.fields[2].offset; // Z has an offset of 8
    
        float X = 0.0;
        float Y = 0.0;
        float Z = 0.0;

        // Copy the data directly from the location in the message
        memcpy(&X, &pCloud.data[arrayPosX], sizeof(float));
        memcpy(&Y, &pCloud.data[arrayPosY], sizeof(float));
        memcpy(&Z, &pCloud.data[arrayPosZ], sizeof(float));
       
        if(not(isnan(X)) & not(isnan(Y)) & not(isnan(Z)))
        {
            if((0.05 < Z) & (Z < 2.0))
            {
                ROS_INFO("check1");
                ROS_INFO_STREAM(X);
                pt.x = X;
                pt.y = Y;
                pt.z = Z;
            }
        } 

        obj_coords.points[i].insert(0, pt);   
    }
    
    // select lowest Z
    ROS_INFO("check3");
    point_pub.publish(obj_coords);  
}
```

The program progresses to check2, but does not reach check3 after constructing the message. I know for a fact that the values in pt are correct. However it won't store them in obj_coords.points. I am guessing this is caused by my attempt to itterate through the list adding points until all relevant xy combinations are combined with their appropriate z.

How would I go about properly storing all coordinates in the message?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320670/building-msg-in-c++/) by [THordijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40618/thordijk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
Just an observation:

> ```
> float X = 0.0;
> ```

```
memcpy(&X, &pCloud.data[arrayPosX], sizeof(float));
```

What is the difference with `X = pCloud.data[arrayPosX]`?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:\

> The program progresses to check2, but does not reach check3 after constructing the message.

there is no `check3` in the code you show.

> However it won't store them in obj_coords.points.

and how have you determined this?

**Comment by [bsaund](https://answers.ros.org/users/29303/bsaund/) on 2019-04-09**:
Use `&&` instead of `&` for boolean logic

**Comment by [bsaund](https://answers.ros.org/users/29303/bsaund/) on 2019-04-09**:
Posting the specific error you are receiving will help us solve the problem

**Comment by [THordijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40618/thordijk/) on 2019-04-09**:
gvdhoorn, I took the code from someone else, I am not very familiar with c++ so I could not tell you the difference. If there is none then I will use your suggestion, as it much cleaner.
I have determined that it does not reach check 3 (edited in main question) by running the program in combination with the other nodes. The program crashes between check2 and 3.

bsaund What would be the functional difference between & and &&, that part of the code seems to be working properly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:\

> Use `&&` instead of `&` for boolean logic

this is a good comment, but in the end it doesn't really matter here I believe: the if-clause consists of two predicates. With the boolean<->integer coercion in C++, the clause translates to a binary AND of two integers. The integers will be either 0 or 1. So in the end the entire clause will only be `1` if both subclauses are `true == 1`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
As long as we're "reviewing" this code: the inner loop seems to implement a filter, but the method is called `pixelTo3DPoint(..)`. That seems like a disconnect there.

**Comment by [THordijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40618/thordijk/) on 2019-04-09**:
The code takes pixel values x and y and retrieves the corresponding xyz coordinates. What would you call it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
So what is this doing in there then?

> ```
> if((0.05 < Z) & (Z < 2.0))
> ```

that looks like it's filtering points based on their Z value.

**Comment by [THordijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40618/thordijk/) on 2019-04-09**:
True, I got values far from what was reasonable. I use this to filter a range based on Z values.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
That would seem to violate the separation of concerns principle.

**Comment by [THordijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40618/thordijk/) on 2019-04-10**:
What is the difference with X = pCloud.data[arrayPosX]?

I tried this and it does not return anything, can not tell you why though.

```
That would seem to violate the separation of concerns principle.
```

I am not familiar with this principle. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> coord_proces::xyz obj_coords;
> ```

```
[..]
obj_coords.points[i] = pt;
```

`obj_coords.points` is a `std::vector` (see [wiki/msg: Message Description Specification](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification)). You cannot just index into a `std::vector` without first reserving space for the objects. You must either first [reserve(..)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) or you should use [push_back(..)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

> The next node uses these coordinates to filter a distance from a pointcloud msg.

From the code it looks like you're essentially implementing a passthrough filter with a threshold for `Z` set to min 5cm and max 2m. You might want to take a look at [pcl/documentation/Filtering a PointCloud using a PassThrough filter](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php) which essentially does the same thing, but in much less lines (and potentially more efficient).

---

Edit:

> The program crashes between check2 and 3.

that would be one symptom of using memory past the end of the vector, which would be another indication that not `reserve(..)`ing and not using `push_back(..)` is the most likely cause here.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [THordijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40618/thordijk/) on 2019-04-09**:
This worked thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
Please note: this is more a general C++ related issue than an actual ROS question. The fact that ROS messages are being used is not that important (in the end it's just a regular C++ `std::vector`, and that was being used incorrectly).

While we're all here to help, it might be more efficient to post these sort of queries on dedicated C++ fora.

**Comment by [THordijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40618/thordijk/) on 2019-04-09**:
Noted. from now i'll go there first.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of `obj_coords.points[i] = pt`, use `obj_coords.push_back(pt)`.

`obj_coords.points` is a `vector`, and is initialized with size 0, so you are trying to access an element off the end.

---

Originally posted by [bsaund](https://answers.ros.org/users/29303/bsaund/) with karma: 161 on 2019-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [THordijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/40618/thordijk/) on 2019-04-09**:
This worked thank you! I did need to keep points in the statement.